# Swift Remove a given value from an array

Tags: iphone, swift, ios8

I have a simple array with

```
var specs : [String] = [Button1,Button2,Button3,Button4]
```

How can I find a certain value (type Button3) in my erray and therefore cancel?

Comment: find(specs, Button3)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `find()` global function to retrieve the index:

```
var specs : [String] = ["Button1","Button2","Button3","Button4"]

let index = find(specs, "Button3")
```

and then, once verified that the element exists (`find` returns an optional), remove it:

```
if let index = index {
    specs.removeAtIndex(index)
}
```

Comment: and for remove a value